# Buck converter driver LTC4446 running too hot, too high current

Tags: buck, driver

[image]
I am trying to design a buck converter, but the driver LTC4446 is getting to hot with this design and the input current is also to high (130 mA), when it should be in the uA orders... Any ideas of why this might be happening?

Thanks

[EDIT]

Regarding some of the questions asked, here is the circuit in Eagle, my question is for the real circuit. I am also connecting a load of 1.5ohms in the real circuit. The reference of the inductor being used is a HCTI 10-20 of 10uH. The other components used are specified in the circuit layout. Again thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you doing to prevent shoot-through?

Comment: Since you posted a graphic of a simulation screen I have to double-check if you are obtaining 130 mA in simulation or with a real circuit. Do you also have an actual circuit you are testing?

Comment: If you _do_ have an actual circuit, please post a shot of the layout around the converter.  Layout matters a _lot_ in RF circuits and switching supplies; you should just make habit of showing it.

Comment: More information needed for good answers. 130 mA with load? No load ? . Inductor used? Datasheet links to IC, core, ... . | Helping people help you avoids question closure.

Comment: I edited the original post based on your questions. Thanks again, regarding shoot-through, well the pwm signal of Binp is the complementary signal of Tinp.

Comment: @JorgeFelipeGaviriaFierro  Better but still unclear. Is the 130 mA with load? What is Vin and Vout (stated in text is far better than trying to determine from diagram). |
 What is the loaded and unloaded Vin, Iin, Vout, )=(Iout), Rl